# update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x-terminal-emulator

Tags: linux, terminal, opensuse, linux-terminal

I have openSUSE Tumbleweed. I want to change default terminal emulator from `xterm` to `konsole`, BUT when I get command

```
update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

I have this:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x-terminal-emulator
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

opsenSUSE with i3wn, I have changed this in `~/.config/i3/config:

```
bindsym $mod+Return exec i3-sensible-terminal
```

on this:

```
bindsym $mod+Return exec konsole
```

sorry